# Button does not show next to a webview

Tags: android, android-layout, button, webview, tabs

my app consists of a tab-widged activity. In one tab I show a webview under which I want to present several buttons. 
The Code I posted works now!

Thanks for the Help

```
package com.whateveryoulike.whateveryoulike;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity_tab_reader extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

// entnimmt die url aus dem public static string und legt sie in der localen string    mynewurl ab.
String MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;
//String data = "<html><head></head><body>this should be my long long text...</body></html>";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_reader);

    MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl(MyNewUrl);

    //Settings webview
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

    final Activity activity = this;

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });     
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!MyNewUrl.equals(Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL)){

            MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;   
            webView.loadUrl(MyNewUrl);

        }
    }
}
```

this is the tabxmlfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fh_blau"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCloseSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: "I have tried literally everything but without success" I'm not sure you understand the word ["literal"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literal) but you should show us your latest attempt, at least

Comment: did you try shotgun debugging?

Comment: "The buttons are not there!" you're right. Where are the buttons that you think should be there? You set the webview in `setContentView()` so I'm not sure what else you expect to show up...

Comment: @codeMagic might be so. I am from germany so my english is not failfree. Added the javacode. Intended to do so from the start but stackoverflow kept on remarking me that code was outside of the codearea....

Comment: Ok, well I linked to it so you can understand it's meaning. But it means there is absolutely nothing that you haven't tried which isn't possible. Anyway, I'm still not sure where the buttons are that you expect to see.

Comment: @SargeBorsch ist shotgun debugging not exactly that? trying everything?

Comment: @codeMagic what do you propose I should set the contetnt view to?

Comment: Your xml file with the buttons and a webview or else add the webview to the layout after calling `setContentView()`

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: setContenView(tabxml.xml); or how should I do it??

Comment: @codeMagic how do I set the contentview to my xml file?

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.myXMLFile);`

Comment: @codeMagic ok I did it.... now I cant see my buttons and the webview turns out to be blank instead of showing my html file

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what you have without you posting it. You have something wrong but I can't see it to know what. But I'm pretty sure it's not a bug in the framework

Comment: what do you need? I can post everything just say what you want to see

Comment: just edited my post so you can see my xml file but I am fairly shure that the problem is not inside the xmlfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you edited question, below code should work, and when you use a RelativeLayout, you must let the widgets know, where they needs to be, use layout_above/layout_below and properties of RelativeLayout
EDIT:  i have added a `setContentView(R.id.tab)` change "tab" with your xml file name.
and try to learn the code before you copy paste it

Your Activity,

```
 public class Activity_tab_reader extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    // entnimmt die url aus dem public static string und legt sie in der localen string mynewurl ab.
    String MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);
        webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//    do the same as above here to initialize buttons and handle their clicks.
    MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;   
        webView.loadUrl(MyNewUrl);
        //webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        final Activity activity = this;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    //  webView .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!MyNewUrl.equals(Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL)){

            MyNewUrl =  Activity_Haupt.MyDocumentURL;   
            webView.loadUrl(MyNewUrl);
        }
    }
```

and the tab xmlfile,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fh_blau"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCloseSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but that doesn't work. I am fairly sure that the problem lies outside of the xmlfile.

Comment: @NMev, you activity was coded wrongly a bit, you should use setContentView() to handle multiple widgets in a screen and to notify activity that you has a particular xml to show in this activity , Try changing both my xml and my edited class.

Comment: hey I didn't spot the changes you did in the java file... now I see my buttons but the webview shows a blank but thats more than I achieved all day. thanks

Comment: It all works perfekt now and I am going to change my posted code to the right one in an hour.... thanks alot